# Can i import a .sql file from wamp to xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp, wamp

i have a .sql file that was exported from wamp, my friend only uses xampp. Is it possible to import my .sql file to xampp?

Comment: It is possible. You should at least have tried to import it before asking.

Comment: @besciualex i think his friend is novice and couldn't have tried to import, also himself have not xampp on his system, Then he was forced to ask... :)

Comment: @Fatemeh You might be right. What I meant is "Try! If you don't succeed then ask." when it comes to not critical things. By critical I meant that he couldn't do anything bad to actual database, by importing something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because the .sql file is most likely independent of the server stack.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, when wamp give you a export of .sql, this file can be used with all standard web server. (*xampp*)

Answer (score 0):

**I think this may help**

Depending on the tool and parameters used to create the .sql dump file of multiple databases, the file will normally have

```
CREATE DATABASE DBn...;
```

and

```
USE DBn;
```

statements that will allow your import to proceed without hiccups. For example, both the mysqldump command mysqldump command and phpMyAdmin's Export function for multiple database insert them.

Assuming you have exported with a sensible tool like those above, then you can import the database with a command line like this:

```
mysql -u username -p < dumpfile.sql
```

Your mysql username account needs to have appropriate privileges to, for example, create databases.

You can even run this command in a more familiar way by naming the startingDB database to use before running the commands in **dumpfile.sql**:

```
mysql -u username -p startingDB < dumpfile.sql
```